# How is possible add child to the specific node

Tags: php, xml

This is my starting xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <child>
        <children></children>
     </child>
    </root>
```

and I wanna add other children in child?? but I'm trying and nothing I don't know how... :S help pls I want to my xml be to like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <root>
      <child>
        <children></children>
        <children></children>
     </child>
    </root>
```

Here is my code :

```
<?php
            $dom = new DomDocument;
            //$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
            $dom->load("myXML.xml");
            $root = $dom->getElementById('root');
            $params = $dom->getElementsByTagName('child');
            $cantidadCategorias = $params->length+1;

            $newElement = $dom->createElement('child','');
            $dom->appendChild($newElement);
            $f = fopen("myXML.xml",'w+'); 
            fwrite($f,$dom->saveXML()); 
            fclose($f);
```

Comment: What are you using to generate your XML? Please add more details.

Comment: Please post the code you were trying with and specify at which part you're stuck. It's clear what you try to achieve in your question, but not where you've got the problem with that, so better share a bit more.

Comment: well the XML is already created, but I handle it with php

Comment: How do you handle it with php?

Comment: Because you append it to the root node (`$root`) and not to the node of the `<child>` element. See my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) it's as easy as this:

```
$child = new DOMElement('children');
$parent->appendChild($child);
```

Whereas `$parent` is the `DOMElement` parent which (after you have updated your question) to aquire is part of your problem:

```
// append <children> to the first <child> element
$parent = $dom->getElementsByTagName('child')->item(0);
$child = new DOMElement('children');
$parent->appendChild($child);
```

Comment: See that line: `$parent = $dom->getElementsByTagName('child')->item(0);`

Comment: Excelent dude ty with getELementByTagName()->item :D

Comment: An additional tip: instead of `fopen`... you can just use [`DOMDocument::save()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php) - that's the counterpart to `DOMDocument::load()` you use at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged php i am assuming you are looking for a solution in PHP
did you try the following:

```
$myxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$myxml->child[0]->addChild('children');
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php for a good set of examples on XML manipulation in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Some good examples on how to append XML nodes can be found in the PHP manual.  Like this [one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php) on how to use the [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) class to add a child node.